# Writing code to connect points on the HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have been trying to write code that will connect points on an HTML5 canvas, but nothing seems to be appearing on the canvas when I use my function. I am not sure why it isn't working. Even when I give it input that I know shouldn't be a problem, it doesn't work.

It is this:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#cnv-ex");

class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function drawLine(canvas, spt, ept, style, rotation) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    
    if (rotation != 0) {
        context.translate(spt.x, spt.y);
        context.rotate(rotation);
        context.translate(-spt.x, -spt.y);
    }
    
    context.strokeStyle = style;
    
    context.moveTo(spt.x, spt.y);
    context.lineTo(ept.x, ept.y);
    
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

function drawField(calculatedFields) {
  for (var i = 0; i < calculatedFields.length; i++) {
    var pair = calculatedFields[i];
            
    var start = new Point(calculatedFields[i][1][0].x, calculatedFields[i][1][0].y);
    var end;
            
    var stroke = "purple";
            
    for (var j = 0; j > pair[1].length; j++) {
      if (j != pair[1].length - 1) end = pair[1][j + 1];
      else break;
                
      drawLine(canvas,
        start,
        end,
        stroke,
        0);
                    
      start = end;
     }
   }
}

//sample input: (includes some points off the canvas, because that sometimes occurs when it is used with the rest of the program)
const fields = [
  [3, [
      {x: 3, y: 3},
      {x: 3, y: 5},
      {x: 4, y: 6},
      {x: 5, y: 8}
    ]
  ],
  [9, [
      {x: 7, y: 8},
      {x: 5, y: 7},
      {x: 434, y: 54},
      {x: -4, y: 8}
    ]
  ],
  [6, [
      {x: 46, y: 36},
      {x: 565, y: 55},
      {x: 435, y: 401},
      {x: 234, y: 24}
    ]
  ]
];

drawField(fields);
```

```css
#cnv-ex {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="600" height="400" id="cnv-ex">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, this code does not draw anything onto the canvas. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you draw a single point? I would disect the problem in very small pieces. First, draw a point, then draw line and then build complexity up step by step.

Comment: `if (j != pair[1].length - 1) end = pair[1][j + 1];
      else break;` looks like a problem. `pair[1][j + 1]` is 1 past the length, which would be 2 too long. `end = pair[1][j - 1];` would make more sense. There's really no need for the if condition before that, if you want to go to the end of the loop.

Comment: @StackSlave - no that part is ok, just really smelly code. John found it `>` instead of `<`. Should close due to not reproducible

Comment: Oh dear, this is quite a facepalm. Anyone who knows how to mark this as not reproducible (/ is able to) should. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this for next loop

```
for (var j = 0; j > pair[1].length; j++) {
```

The > needs to be <

Comment: This should really be a comment with a close vote as not reproducible. But good catch! :-)